# Check if file exist inside custom folder in Downloads - getExternalStoragePublicDirectory deprecated

Tags: android, file, pdf, file-exists

What I'm trying to achieve is to check before download if the file exists so i don't have to re-download it again. For example, i have to open for the first time this pdf from the Internet "history-of-comics.pdf", in order to do so i have to download it and open inside my app, the second time i choose to re-read it, i have to be sure that "history-of-comics.pdf" if exists inside Downloads/MyDocs, i don't have to waste resources and let the user wait to download it again. Currently the  app targetSdkVersion is 29 and what i have done so far is:

1. Give permissions for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
2. Included in manifest android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" inside application tag
3. Download the pdf file in the MyDocs inside Downloads folder

Below is a quick sample of my code (i have commented the other combinations i have tried):

```js
 private void checkIfPdfExists(String pdfFileName) {
        String uriFile = String.valueOf(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.separator+"MyDocs"+File.separator+pdfFileName+".pdf"));
        File file = new File(uriFile);
        
        //File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/MyDocs", pdfFileName+".pdf");
        //File file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.separatorChar+"MyDocs"+File.separatorChar+pdfFileName+".pdf");
        //File file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.separatorChar+"MyDocs", pdfFileName+".pdf");
        if (file.exists() && file!=null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.getPath() + "/n exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            displayFromUri(Uri.parse(file.getPath()));
        } else {
            beginDownload("https://www.heritagestatic.com/comics/d/history-of-comics.pdf",pdfFileName);
        }
    }
```

And this is how i define the path when i download the pdf, the downloader works as it should:

```js
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/pdf");
        request.setDescription(file_name);
        request.setTitle("Getting your doc");
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"MyDocs/"+file_name+".pdf");
```

I did some research before posting the question and in some threads i found that is related to Android Q, but i can't find a real solution for it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTOR_DOWNLOADS), "MyDocs/Pdffilename.pdf");

Comment: Your only problem was using the right path to your file.

Comment: `if (file.exists() && file!=null) ` That should be `if ((file!=null ) && file.exists())` Otherwise you still would get a NullPointerException if file was null. But you can better remove the check as file will never be null.

Comment: @blackapps thank you very much for the help. The method you told me seems to work fine, the only "issue" is that "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory" is deprecated and the application I'm working on is being tested in a lot of Android Q and Android R beta, that's why i have included Q in subject. I tried with "context.getExternalFilesDir" instead of "Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory" but it returns always this file exists, meanwhile it doesn't. Can you give me some directions regarding this please? Thanks again!

Comment: @blackapps the only reason i included request legacy to manifest was to find a quick solution, then i found out that on Android Q/R you can't use getExternalStorageDirectory as you mentioned. Please can you share with me if you have any information how to solve this scenario without android:requestLegacyExternalStorage ? Thanks!

Comment: The scenario is as follows. If you can use and use `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` then you check with `getExternalStrorageDirectory()`. If you download to `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir() ` then with `getExternalFilesDir()`. And so on.

Comment: @blackapps you are the real MVP, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was how i was referring to file path and the method used for download. As @blackapps mentioned that if you use "setDestinationInExternalFilesDir" to save the file, the proper way to check if the file exist is with "getExternalFilesDir", in my case:

```
 File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+File.separator+"MyDocs"+File.separator+pdfFileName+".pdf");
```